# Metal Studs - How they should be installed?

Tags: framing, metal

What is the way metal stud should be installed? Is there a reason they should be, a same way, as in upside down? And precut - holes line up.

Comment: They typically only go one way. Or rather, there is no "up" vs. "down", and as far as like "C" or a "backwards "C" - well whichever way you do it you should be consistent within a given wall. But it won't make a difference structurally (Northern hemisphere this way, australia the reverse? No.) and even if you are not consistent within a wall, it won't matter once the dryall is up.

Comment: As far as structural,can see that.  But when you run wire or water lines.  I walk away and shack my head, Looks like a home owner pulled  MC  To the point i put in my own holes.And how many holes can you put in a 10 foot stud not carrying a load  And a wall that does .You can not hack them up.

Comment: I have put in the bushings.  And one way they seem fine.And the other way they move around.  Not to my liking,

Comment: This is going out to a guy that does nothing but metal studs every day.What is the    C?

Comment: Can you talk about the '   C

Comment: push the end of the metal stud against soft ground, then look at the imprint left behind

Comment: Is that a matter of starting at the left and working to the right ?For layout of drywall.Good point i did not know that matters.What do the precut holes in the stud mean?  Looks like a   A =bomb round at top then goes to a inch slot What way should that be ?Slot down or up ?

Comment: When slot down ,bushings were fine . Slot up loose as heck.

Comment: This may sound dumb ,and i should let it go.But i do not want to make my own holes and weaken walls   And end up in a world of hurt.

Comment: is this what you have? .... http://pacwalls.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/1749/2018/10/t-bar.png

Comment: That is great pic ,the slot seem to stiffing the studs and wide part up.Is up. Is that is the way they should be by code .

Comment: Slot down.And my work is wright.Or it does not matter?

Comment: i think that the crossbars are not firmly attached ....  they are wider than the slot and have notches to allow them to drop into the slot .... the crossbars probably become useless if the stud is upside down

Comment: Wow  That makes sense so much.  Clearly it is not me..They have to fix studs  upside down.That was a lot of help

Comment: Pic and a commet should be answer

Comment: What I mean by the "C" is that a metal stud has a long side (e.g., 3-5/8" in one I just checked) and two shorter sides (e.g., 1-1/4") - so if you look at the stud on the end it looks (sort of) like a "C". And that which way the "C" faces makes no difference structurally, though if you put some one way and some the opposite way in the same wall then it will look rather strange and be marginally harder to run cables, etc. though once the wall is closed it will make no real difference. My only real experience with metal studs is occasionally running network/phone cables through metal stud walls.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it matters how the studs are placed.  All should be facing the same C pattern. And the larger hole points up, so that if doing taller walls the metal stiffeners do not fall out.